# It is possible to run Visual Studio on a VM on macbook M1 and compile x86/x64 .net binaries?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, apple-silicon

As the title says. I’m evaluating updating my workstation which is a 2019 Macbook Pro (intel) to the newer 2021 Macbook Pro (arm)

My work involves having a windows  Fusion VM for running VS and compile/debug c# projects

Comment: Basically no you cannot run Intel Windows in a perfrmany way on an Apple Silicon Mac. If you only use .Net Core then there is a Mac Visual Studio Preview which includes .NET and c# and f# compilers .Net is cross platform

Comment: Running Windows for ARM on a VM, then Visual Studio on it, is not possible?

Comment: Windows VS is Intel code only - see [MS docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-on-arm-devices?view=vs-2022) . MS recommends "For the best experience, we recommend you use Visual Studio on a separate, x86 powered, computer, and use the remote deployment and debugging features in Visual Studio to target the ARM-based device."

Comment: If you are writing Windows programs I would get a Windows computer